# Will an edit to an answer I made be known to the person who asked the question?

Tags: support

Or do I have to add a comment so that the questioner is notified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no system in place to pro-actively notify askers when answers to their questions are edited. The edit history is public though, so anyone seeking the information can just click the 'Edited January 1st' (or whatever date) below the question to view the details.

If you make an edit and want to make it more likely the asker sees it, either leave them a comment or 'ping' them in chat so they get a notification.

Realize that many questions here are abandoned or forgotten, so there is no guarantee the questioner will ever see your edit.

Comment: You do actually get an alert, asking you to approve the suggested edit. :-)

Comment: @jrg Only if the editor doesn't have enough rep to edit without being subject to review. Also, if the edit has to be approved but gets approved very quickly, and then the original author logs in much later, the notification doesn't appear, does it?

Comment: @eliah it appears. I get them all the time. they are generally approved, but I get them.

Comment: @jrg I can't remember ever seeing such a notification.

Comment: @TomBrossman guess people don't suggest edits for your questions?